# Grails ACL plugin

Tags: grails

I wanted to use grails acl plugin in my application to authenticate access. At first i followed the 
http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-acl/docs/manual/guide/single.html#3.%20Tutorial

But problem is when i run the application and try to login then the message showing "Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password." What should i do? should i create tables in my database? Although i have followed all the steps mentioned in the tutorial.

Any help will be appreciable
Thanks.

Comment: Have you ran s2-quickstart for user and role domain? Have you stored any user in the system ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. yes i did. finally it worked. i added grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.encodeHashAsBase64 = true in config.groovy, changed password:springSecurityService.encodePassword('admin123') as       def admin = new User(username: 'admin', enabled: true,password: 'admin123').save() in BootStrap.groovy.